# In the HashMap of Java, will removing an element from keySet affect the hashmap object?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

Let's say I have a HashMap called `myMap`, then I get a `keySet` object from it and modify the `keySet`

```
Set<Integer> keys = myMap.keySet();
keys.remove(1);
keys.remove(2);
```

If myMap contains `1` and `2` as keys before this snippet, will `myMap` be changed after this snippet is executed?

Comment: Return value of `keySet()`, `values()` and `entrySet()` are backed by the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Removing elements from the key set removes the corresponding entries from the map. Quoting the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--):

> The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the `Iterator.remove`, `Set.remove`, `removeAll`, `retainAll`, and `clear` operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
jshell> HashMap<Integer, Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
a ==> {}

jshell> Set<Integer> b = a.keySet();
b ==> []

jshell> b
b ==> []

jshell> a.put(1,2)
$4 ==> null

jshell> a
a ==> {1=2}

jshell> b
b ==> [1]

jshell> b.remove(1)
$7 ==> true

jshell> a
a ==> {}

jshell> b
b ==> []
```

The answer is Yes.

Comment: This is a poor answer (IMO).  This is merely evidence of this behavior in one implementation of Java.  The proof is that the javadocs *specify* this behavior ... and this behavior is consistent for all versions of Java that specify the `Map` API.

Comment: agree, just post here as a supplementary